# In MongoDB, how can I update a document which contains a value in an attribute and wants to add more values to that attribute?

Tags: database, mongodb

I want to add more values into a field with only one value in MongoDB.

Below is the code in inserting the document of an Ed Sheeran song to the *playlist* collection:

[image]

Below is the output of Ed Sheeran document after using the *find* and *pretty* methods:

[image: The document an Ed Sheeran's song]

I keep getting an error every time I add more songs using the *update* method and the $*set* operator:

[image]

Comment: the first argument should be an object like this: `{_id:ObjectId("xxxxxxx")}`. currently you seem to be missing the curly braces.